# NetBeans; How to Listen for Project Created/Opened/Closed Events

Tags: netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I created a NetBeans module with, among other things, a custom project type. Then I decided to move some of the project-related stuff, including actions related to opening, creating and closing a project, to a separate library, to reduce dependency on the NetBeans platform.

Now I need to call code in the library when project is created, opened or closed in NetBeans, but I don't know how to get notified of those events. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend a [ProjectOpenedHook](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-projectuiapi/org/netbeans/spi/project/ui/ProjectOpenedHook.html) implementing the appropriate methods and ten add your extension to your Project's Lookup

Comment: Excellent, thanks Antonio :) Is there a way to create the project outside of NetBeans, but still have the project type shown in the list of samples? I thought I could create an empty project template and call the external code at some point during the empty project creation... It should work that way, but it's a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Antonio's suggestion works great, I just want to add some extra info.

- To create a project, I created a Project Template, from an empty project. In the generated WizardIterator class, I replaced the call to unZipFile() with call my Project.create()
- ProjectFactory's loadProject() method can also be used to trigger logic related to opening a project.
- I handle project closing as Antonio suggested.

Comment: loadProject() can be called on a project that is not opened. Eg. via FileOwnerQuery